# Making GET call to php from javascript WITHOUT ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xss

I have this small piece of javascript code that passes a string to a php file, and waits for the JSON that comes back to render in an alert box.  The problem is due to the cross sight issues I don't think the AJAX is working.

This is what I had for the javascript:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><script type="text/javascript"> 
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var params = x; 
http.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
   alert(http.responseText);
   alert(http.responseXML);

   if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200)
     {

     }
  }
  http.open("GET","http://someserver.somesight.edu/scripts/auth.php?name=" +    params,true);
  http.send();
</script></p>
```

So that is my javascript makes a call to a PHP and then gets back a JSON string.  I want to do more with this string but for now I want to just get SOMETHING back.  Its not though and I am thinking its a domain issue (whatever that is called where javascript wont allow you to do ajax requests from different domains).

This is my php script:

```
<?php
 include("config.php"); 
 include("JSON.php");
 $selectedusername = $_GET['name'];
 $resultstring = connectToLDAP($selectedusername); //some function
 $echo $resultstring;  //the json string
?>
```

This seems simple enough yet sure enough the alert boxes in the javascript have blank and a null. I thought there was a non ajax way to make the php call to get back whatever string was being echoed cause I still would like to process on that more...

So is there something grossly wrong here?  I should note that I am not familiar as to what level the scripts are not allowed to post cross site.  The javascript is hosted on

my.somesight.edu

and the site is it trying to goto is

someother.somesight.edu

I thought it being the main domain it was okay, but since its not working apparently not (or my code is just broke)

FIDDLER RESULTS:

It does an https tunnel from the site the javascript is on...this is websession 3 to 9.  Then websession 10 hits the site that has the php script on it:

```
 [RAW VIEW CLICKING ON THAT WEB SESSION]
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 21:07:39 GMT
 Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
 Content-Length: 53
 Connection: close
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 {"messagetype":"none","message":"time good","url":""}
```

So that looks good, that JSON is what I want back in my javascript..just nothing happens.

Comment: AJAX does not work cross-domain without using JSONP.

Comment: You execute `http.send();` before defining `http.onreadystatechange` function - switch the order

Comment: Switching the order still resulted in empty responseText and XML.   I am going to research more if I have access to change the scripting options and use JSONP

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Fiddler, and look at the requests you send and receive from the server. 
Post them here if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: Hey this fiddler is cool.  I didn't know it had exsisted.  I am trying to figure out how to use it, and find the requests and response from the server to post.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent cross site issues with CORS and JSONP. If you have access / management right to the server you can set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and cross domain is not cross domain anymore.
Other option is JSONP - that uses cross domain GET requests through a script block. Result which is in json gets evaled, as your callback function gets called with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your php is echoing back a plain string. You don't want a plain string; you want JSON-encoded data.

[PHP Manual json-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

So in your example, try:

```
echo json_encode($resultstring);
```

Also, you will need to make sure that your Javascript is listening for JSON data to be returned. I recommend you try jQuery's [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) ajax method. Very simple to use.

Comment: actually the connect to ldap function returns a json string already.  its just a string so echoing it back should be just fine.

Comment: Ah just realized OP asked for a non-ajax solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code does not return any data here:

```js
 if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200)
 {

 }
```

It should be

```js
 if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
     alert(http.responseText);
     //or
     document.write(http.responseText);
     //or
     document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = http.responseText;
 }
```